# Getting data from REST API in Synapse with pagination rules giving invalid JSON structure

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm getting data from SAP Success Factors using the REST API in Azure Synapse Analytics with Copy data activity. Below the structure of the body returned by the REST api:

```
    {
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "object1": "test1"
            },
            {
                "object2": "test2"
            }
        ],
        "__next": "mynexturl"
    }
}
```

I set the pagination rules to: ['d']['__next']:
[image]
(I'm precising that if I put a $ in the pagination rules: $['d']['__next'] or $.d.__next according to the official MS documentation, I'm getting only the first 1000 rows).

With this I'm getting all data but it doesn't concatenate all objects in the "results" node, instead it's just appending the entire structure:

```
    {
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "object1": "test1"
            },
            {
                "object2": "test2"
            }
        ],
        "__next": "mynexturl"
    }
}
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "object3": "test3"
            },
            {
                "object4": "test4"
            }
        ],
        "__next": "mynexturl"
    }
}
```

While I'm trying to get this:

```
    {
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "object1": "test1"
            },
            {
                "object2": "test2"
            },
            {
                "object3": "test3"
            },
            {
                "object4": "test4"
            }
        ],
        "__next": "mynexturl"
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid an approach with a foreach loop that would write multiple json and then merge them into one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment
and getting similar result with next links.

Sample data with next links:
[image]

To work around this you can use `Mapping` Option and import the schema of the json output.
[image]

Then delete the unwanted Sections:
[image]

Edit the destination column json path and then Copy it.
document for [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping)